# Azure Logic App: How do I pass a single For Each variable to an Execute Stored Procedure step?

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic App to execute a stored procedure that accepts a string input.

Here is the definition of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [ResMgmt].[usp_ExtractReportBlob] 
     (@ReportFileName VARCHAR(255),
      @ReportBlobName VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX), 
            @ReportSPROCName VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @ReportSPROCName = (SELECT ReportSPROCName
                            FROM ResMgmt.ReportMetadata
                            WHERE ReportFileName = @ReportFileName);

    SET @SQL = 'EXEC ' + @ReportSPROCName + ';';

    SELECT (@SQL);

    SET @ReportBlobName = '/<azure-storage>/' + @ReportFileName;

    RETURN @ReportBlobName;
END;
```

The stored procedure ultimately outputs a string that will be used by Logic App, but first thing's first... I cannot get my `Attachments Name` iterator to be used as an input for the stored procedure. The stored procedure accepts parameter `ReportFileName`, which will be coming from the iterator of the For Each step:

[image: For each step]

You can see that, in the code view, I am referencing the `item()` dynamically in the `body` key of the `json` structure:

[image: Logic App code view]

But I end up with this error in debug:

[image: Error]

When I run from debug, I get the error above. It seems like the `json` format is correct, so I don't understand why the error is occurring. For example, I can confirm that the correct string value `DTG Active Client List Daily.csv` is getting passed to the stored procedure key `ReportFileName`.

How do I pass this variable to my stored procedure?

Comment: What you've got looks fine. I'd keep trying this and/or report to Microsoft. Seems something similar happened earlier this month. Check the answer here, it was a problem with the Azure REST API. [Getting Error on HTTP POST Connector - "BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON."](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e103719-b280-4f68-b0c2-66cc036d0911/getting-error-on-http-post-connector-quotbadrequest-http-request-failed-the-content-was-not-a?forum=azurelogicapps)

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, and it's very simple.  I decided to switch to `Execute a SQL Query` step for ease, but it worked under the old method as well.

I am passing a string variable to my stored procedure.  The `json` "looks" correct because it's contained within double-ticks (e.g. `" "`).  But the stored procedure is expecting a string contained within single-ticks (e.g. `' '`).  I had to manually wrap my variable with the single-ticks.

Like so:

[image]